# Typescript, React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

Seems like a stupid problem, but I can't find out why it occures and what I did wrong even after I read error message and tried to find this sort of problem here

So the main goal is to add a book object into library array. No problems whit states, at least now, the should work correctly (console.log shows that everything's OK), exports and imports are correct in all files, I even have snippets in HiddenPanel.tsx file to use Library methods from Library.ts

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
Function.push../src/Library.ts.Library.addBook
src/Library.ts:36

Line 36:

```
Library.library.push(book)
```

Quick problem description: some problem with types which I can't figure out. Occures after pressing ADD (which calls push() from method in Library.class)

Files:
1. HiddenPanel.tsx
2. Library.ts

I have a Book class with constructor (Library.ts)

```
class Book {
    constructor(public author: string, public title: string, public pages: string, public rating: number) {
        title = title
        author = author
        pages = pages
        rating = rating
    }     
}
```

Book constructor call-method is located in Library class (Library.ts)

```
class Library {
    static library: Array<object>

    library = [
        {
        author: 'Johann Fjord Kallenberg',
        title: 'Norvegian dragonslayers',
        pages: '443',
        rating: 4
        }, {
        author: 'Dungo McCallahey',
        title: 'Irish Golden Era',
        pages: '318',
        rating: 3
        }, {
        author: 'John Doe Mouse',
        title: 'Preparing to fight a Wolfgod',
        pages: '714',
        rating: 4
        }
    ]



public static addBook = (title: string, author: string, pages: string, rating: number) => {

        let book = new Book(title, author, pages, rating)
        Library.library.push(book)
        console.log(Library.library)
    }
}
```

Constructor is being called from HiddenPanel.tsx

```
class HiddenPanel extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            author: '',
            title: '',
            pages: '',
            rating: 0,
            value: '',
        }
    }

    ...some private methods here...

    private handleClick = () => {
        Library.addBook(this.state.author, this.state.title, this.state.pages, this.state.rating)
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="add-book-section">
                ...some stuff here... 
                <div onClick={this.handleClick} className="submit">ADD</div>

                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: in your class definition you need to instantiate Library to initialize the class member library, thats why its undefined...`library = []`

Comment: @AshwynHorton can you, please, tell me where should I do that? I initialized library in Library class already, I tried to do it with an empty array (library = []), and now it seems I don't understand the purpose of (static library: Array<object>). Eslint still gives no errors

Comment: Lol, I changed library: Array<object> to  static library: object[] = Array() and it worked fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue :

If you read the comments and run the below snippet, that will clear the reason behind the issue.

```js
class Library {
    static library: Array<object> // <-- Declared but not initialized
    
    // ---- this is not static property, this will create a property for class
    library = [ 
        {
        author: 'Johann Fjord Kallenberg',
        title: 'Norvegian dragonslayers',
        pages: '443',
        rating: 4
        }, {
        author: 'Dungo McCallahey',
        title: 'Irish Golden Era',
        pages: '318',
        rating: 3
        }, {
        author: 'John Doe Mouse',
        title: 'Preparing to fight a Wolfgod',
        pages: '714',
        rating: 4
        }
    ]
}

console.log( 'Static Property' , Library.library);

const libObj = new Library();
console.log( 'Instance Property' , libObj.library);
```

**Solution :**

You can initialized it with values directly :

```js
class Library {
    static library: Array<object> = [
        {
        author: 'Johann Fjord Kallenberg',
        title: 'Norvegian dragonslayers',
        pages: '443',
        rating: 4
        }, {
        author: 'Dungo McCallahey',
        title: 'Irish Golden Era',
        pages: '318',
        rating: 3
        }, {
        author: 'John Doe Mouse',
        title: 'Preparing to fight a Wolfgod',
        pages: '714',
        rating: 4
        }
    ]
}

console.log( 'Static Property' , Library.library);
```

Comment: @mortvicious, It was interesting also do read the reason behind the issue, glad to know it helped.

Comment: Same. No errors in eslint in this cases is a bit confusing, but u're right, I need to initialize class in the way you provided

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your class like this..

```
class Library {
  static library = [
        {
        author: 'Johann Fjord Kallenberg',
        title: 'Norvegian dragonslayers',
        pages: '443',
        rating: 4
        }, {
        author: 'Dungo McCallahey',
        title: 'Irish Golden Era',
        pages: '318',
        rating: 3
        }, {
        author: 'John Doe Mouse',
        title: 'Preparing to fight a Wolfgod',
        pages: '714',
        rating: 4
        }
    ];
}
```